Find the probability for $a<b$
A dice is weighted such that the probability of rolling the face numbered $n$ is proportional to $n^2$ $(n = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)$ The dice is rolled twice, yielding the numbers $a$ and $b$. The probability that $a < b$ is?
Firstly let k be the proportionality constant
Which gives $k(1^2+2^2+...+6^2)=1$
My approach is that if I think (*) probability as number of favourable cases by total number of cases
Let the total number of cases be $S$
So for example the probability of getting $b = 6$ would be $S\cdot (k(6^2))\cdot k(1^2+2^2+...+5^2)$  I'm multiplying the probability of getting a $6$ with the probability of getting $1$ or $2$ or...or $5$ but now as in the denominator the total number of cases would be squared so I multiplied by an S in order to only get it only once In the denominator as because *
Similarly for getting b=5 the answer would be $Sk^2(5^2)(1^2+2^2+...+4^2)$
now I add the all of those (I mean that im adding all the cases when $b=6,5,4,3,2,1$)
But now the trouble is how do I find $S$?
May someone please explain something about my approach, even if the logic is correct or not? If it's not correct then please explain its reason also.

TBH I probably misunderstood your question but if not...
I'd solve for when a=b then since it is symmetric for a is greater than b and a is less than b divide the remaining probability by two.
Probability for a=b
$1+4+9+16+25+36=91$
$(1/91)^2+(4/91)^2+(9/91)^2+(16/91)^2+(25/91)^2+(36/91)^2=25/91$
Probability for $a<b$
$1-25/91=66/91$
$(66/91)/2 = 33/91$
Sorry my answer was not written well but I think it is $\boxed {\frac {33}{91}}$

Use latex for the formulas

See MathJax.

The math is fine, but you should format it properly.  I made some quick edits, but more should be done.  See this tutorial on formatting for the site.

But could @Zellion could you please explain anything about my approach, even if the logic is correct or not?
